# Laravel update() not working in a foreach even though I have declared $fillable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have some rather ugly code here:

```
foreach($request->assigned['standards'] as $standard){
            if(@$standard['plannings']) {
                foreach($standard['plannings'] as $p) {
                    dump($p['id']);
                    $assigned = PerformanceManagementSetModuleStandardAssignedPlanning::
                        where('id', $p['id'])
                        ->where('performance_management_set_assigned_id', $request->assigned_id)
                        ->first();
                    $assigned->text = $p['text'];
                    $assigned->user_id= 1; //I did this to check that the model was updating, it was
                    dump($assigned);
                    $assigned->update();
                }
            }
        }
```

The record is updating, everything apart from the "text" column. I manually updated the "user_id" column just to make sure, and this updates perfectly fine.

I have text as a fillable property:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PerformanceManagementSetModuleStandardAssignedPlanning extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'text',
    ];
}
```

It can also be seen here when I dump ( dump($assigned) ):

```
App\Models\PerformanceManagementSetModuleStandardAssignedPlanning {#1611
  #fillable: array:1 [
    0 => "text"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "performance_management_set_module_standard_assigned_plannings"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:7 [
    "id" => 307
    "performance_management_set_module_standard_id" => 92
    "performance_management_set_assigned_id" => 110
    "user_id" => 233
    "text" => "134523453452345345234123"
    "created_at" => "2022-05-12 10:06:24"
    "updated_at" => "2022-05-12 10:28:14"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [
    "id" => 307
    "performance_management_set_module_standard_id" => 92
    "performance_management_set_assigned_id" => 110
    "user_id" => 233
    "text" => null
    "created_at" => "2022-05-12 10:06:24"
    "updated_at" => "2022-05-12 10:28:14"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried adding `user_id` to `$fillable`, since that's another field to want to update?

Comment: Have you tried to use save() instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the loop what overwriting, the same ID was being passed each time. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use save() method for that update.

```
foreach($request->assigned['standards'] as $standard){
            if(@$standard['plannings']) {
                foreach($standard['plannings'] as $p) {
                   
                    $assigned = PerformanceManagementSetModuleStandardAssignedPlanning::
                        where('id', $p['id'])
                        ->where('performance_management_set_assigned_id', $request->assigned_id)
                        ->first();
                    $assigned->text = $p['text'];
                    $assigned->user_id= 1; //I did this to check that the model was updating, it was
                    $assigned->save();
                     dump($assigned);
                }
            }
        }
```